# How often do cities refresh their job list?

Tags: ios, pocket-trains

In Nimblebit's Pocket Trains for iOS, you create your train empire by setting up a railroad network and managing your trains to pick up and deliver jobs from one city to another. Gameplay-wise, Pocket Trains is similar to Nimblebit's earlier release, Pocket Planes.

I noticed that jobs aren't refreshed as regularly in Pocket Trains as in Pocket Planes, with the latter having a very visible timer telling you when new jobs are arriving in a city. When are jobs refreshed in a city in Pocket Trains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A post on the Nimblebit support center would suggest that jobs are refreshed for a train each time that train enters a new station.

> Each engine has its own set of jobs that are not visible to other engines in the same station (with the exception of those stored in the yard).  There is not a way to refresh jobs while a train is at a station.  Jobs are refreshed for a train each time it enters a new station.

http://support.nimblebit.com/customer/portal/articles/1304390-refreshing-sharing-and-laying-over-jobs